# If user uses Facebook/Google to login in my website, should I logout a user that logs out from Facebook/Google account?

Tags: login, logout

Is basically the inverse of [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73332/when-logging-out-of-a-website-that-authenticates-with-facebook-should-the-user).

An user register to a website using his/her Facebook account. Should I check if user is still logged in in Facebook and if is not the case log out the user? Or should I log out the user only after user action in the website?

Comment: I think the [answer to the question you linked](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/73333/50654) also answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't log out the user if the user logouts of Facebook/Gmail account because you are using the 3rd party application for authentication and once that is done, it should be fine.

Typically, for the apps that currently work on this system do not do that, otherwise, it would be too much hassle for users.

Answer (score -3):

the logical answer is yes, as logging out of facebook means you are terminating your active facebook session. so any connected sessions on the device like facebook login should be terminated.

This can certainly be a hassle. If this is in the context of being used in a personal device where there is only 1 user, or maybe 2. Then It'll fine to keep the user signed in.

But if this is a publically used device where many people login and log out like a computer in a airport or a cafe, then the above logic should be applied because users might not remember if they logged out of the websites they signed into

Comment: Strongly disagree with "yes". You're only using your Facebook/Google credentials for another site. Unless the Facebook or Google API log you out of other sessions when you log out of Facebook or Google, your site and e.g. Facebook are completely unrelated. Logging out of one shouldn't log out of the other (you are terminating your active *Facebook* session, there's no logical connection). Imagine how nonsensical it would be if logging out of Google logged you out of Stack Exchange, for example. If I ran into a site that behaved this way I'd probably just report it as a bug.